# C++ syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

I just want to see my own datatypes/functions/function parameters with a different color.

I have used [Visual Assist X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Assist_X) before, but it stopped working for some unknown reason. It doesn't color the custom functions or function parameters every time. Also, my trial time is over soon, and I am not going to buy something that doesn't work properly or whose most features I don't even use.

So, if there's any free syntax highlighting that colors all functions, etc. for Visual Studio 2008, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a file(usertype.dat) containing any names, these will be colored differently.

You can read more about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Unfortunately you can't give your different types different colors from there but at least you can get your own types colored.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know that, but it is terribly tedious and I would never actually maintain such a thing.

Comment: yes this is horrible indeed. is it really that visual assist is the only tool for this?

Comment: This would be acceptable if i had multiple files and each file keywords with own colors... so i can see the functions as well. Maybe with some other hack? Or some widget or something, its there some easy way of doing this?

Comment: bump cuz it's the correct answer and i'd give it two bumps for providing the help page with the details.  i just don't like "nullptr" so i do "#define null nullptr", but then it's not blue anymore.  after finding this answer, it's now blue.

Answer (score 1):

To color your own data structures, functions and parameters, a highlighter should know that they are your own data structures, functions and parameters. It means it should be able to parse C++ code. But, C++ code parsing is extremely hard task, so no one will do that just to highlight a couple of words. So, this may be just an associated feature of some powerful tool that definitely costs money.

Actually, it seems there are just some problems with your environment. I use Visual Assist X with Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008 and it works like a charm!

I'd recommend proceeding with Visual Assist X if you are serious about MS VC++ programming. Actually, it is a must have tool as, say, ReSharper for CSharpers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use Visual Studio 2010, there is [Highlighterr](http://highlighterr.codeplex.com/), which changes the colors of classes, structs, macros and typedefs. There doesn’t appear to be a version for Visual Studio 2008, but what are you waiting for? ;-) C++0X awaits…

Comment: I could use Visual Studio 2010 if i just could get it work on my machine. Unfortunately i have some unknown error that prevents me from creating new projects with it (the OK button is disabled). And when i try to convert old version project into new version, it makes conversion errors...